# Why doesn't a FontMetrics' .getStringBounds() return the correct text width?

Tags: java, svg, graphics2d, batik

The code below uses batik-svggen to generate SVG files; the goal is an oh-so-classical goal, but seemingly impossible to get right the first time... Correctly calculate the height and width of some rendered text so that it can be surrounded by a shape -- here, a rectangle.

The class which is used is as follows:

```
public final class SvgParseNode
{
    private static final int LEFTMARGIN = 5;
    private static final int TOPMARGIN = 5;
    private static final int RIGHTMARGIN = 5;
    private static final int BOTTOMARGIN = 5;

    private final Graphics2D graphics;
    private final String text;

    private final int xStart;
    private final int yStart;
    private final int rwidth;
    private final int rheight;
    private final int textXOffset;
    private final int textYOffset;

    @SuppressWarnings("ObjectToString")
    public SvgParseNode(final Graphics2D graphics, final ParseNode node,
        final int xStart, final int yStart)
    {
        this.xStart = xStart;
        this.yStart = yStart;
        this.graphics = Objects.requireNonNull(graphics);
        text = Objects.requireNonNull(node).toString();

        /*
         * First, get the bounds of the text
         */
        final Font font = graphics.getFont();
        final FontMetrics metrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(font);
        final Rectangle2D bounds = metrics.getStringBounds(text, graphics);
        final int boundsHeight = (int) bounds.getHeight();

        /*
         * The width of the target rectangle is that of the bounds width, plus
         * both left and right margin on the x axis
         */
        // PROBLEM HERE
        //rwidth = (int) bounds.getWidth() + LEFTMARGIN + RIGHTMARGIN;
        rwidth = metrics.stringWidth(text) + LEFTMARGIN + RIGHTMARGIN;

        /*
         * The height is that of the bounds height, plus both up and down
         * margins on the y avis
         */
        rheight = boundsHeight + TOPMARGIN + BOTTOMARGIN;

        /*
         * The x offset of the text is that of the left x margin
         */
        textXOffset = LEFTMARGIN;

        /*
         * The y offset is that of half of half the bounds height plus the y
         * up margin
         */
        textYOffset = rheight / 2 + TOPMARGIN;
    }

    public void render()
    {
        final Shape rect = new Rectangle(xStart, yStart, rwidth, rheight);
        graphics.draw(rect);
        graphics.drawString(text, xStart + textXOffset, yStart + textYOffset);
    }

    public Point getTopAttachPoint()
    {
        return new Point(xStart + rwidth / 2, yStart);
    }

    public Point getDownAttachPoint()
    {
        return new Point(xStart + rwidth / 2, yStart + rheight);
    }
}
```

At the line marked `PROBLEM HERE` above, I tried to use the width given by `.getStringBounds()` as the width of the text. Fat luck, it doesn't return the correct result... But the `.stringWidth()` works.

I use this to write the rendering (code adapted from [here](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/svg-generator.html)):

```
public final class SvgWriting
{
    private static final int XSTART = 10;
    private static final int YSTART = 10;

    private static final Path OUTFILE;

    static {
        final String s = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        if (s == null)
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("java.io.tmpdir not defined");

        OUTFILE = Paths.get(s, "t2.svg");
    }

    private SvgWriting()
    {
        throw new Error("no instantiation is permitted");
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        // Get a DOMImplementation.
        final DOMImplementation domImpl =
            GenericDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();

        // Create an instance of org.w3c.dom.Document.
        final String svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        final Document document = domImpl.createDocument(svgNS, "svg", null);

        // Create an instance of the SVG Generator.
        final SVGGraphics2D svgGenerator = new SVGGraphics2D(document);

        final SvgParseNode node = new SvgParseNode(svgGenerator,
            new DummyNode(), XSTART, YSTART);

        node.render();

        try (
            final Writer out = Files.newBufferedWriter(OUTFILE);
        ) {
            svgGenerator.stream(out, false);
        }
    }

    private static final class DummyNode
        extends ParseNode
    {

        private DummyNode()
        {
            super("foo", Collections.emptyList());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "I suck at graphics, I said!";
        }
    }
}
```

What I have noticed is that the longer the text, the "more incorrect" `.getStringBounds()` seems to be; this makes me say that somehow it does not account for the space between each rendered glyph, but that is just a hypothesis.

In the example above, `metrics.getStringBounds(...).getWidth()` returns ~105, and `metrics.stringWidth()` return 111.

Anyway, it is really strange; why doesn't `.getStringBounds()` return a "correct" width? What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know how Batik gets the FontMetrics object, but in JFreeSVG I use a the Graphics2D instance from an small BufferedImage that I keep internal to the SVGGraphics2D object.  To get more accurate font measurements, I have to set a rendering hint on that internal Graphics2D object - basically calling setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON).  Something similar might help you in Batik, or you could substitute JFreeSVG directly and see if it gives you better results.